# How to use PUT method in API with Relationship Data using Entity Framework and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, api

Example: I have a database "Student" with 2 tables:

```
public partial class Class
{  public int ClassId { get; set; }
   public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
public partial class Person
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Phone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ClassId { get; set; }

    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
}
```

How to use PUT method on "Person" class to update a row? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you are mixing things. `PUT` is http verb, which can be used with Web API, whereas Entity Framework is a ORM which allows you to do CRUD operations in a database, using classes as models. You might have read somewhere that `PUT` verb is used to update data and `POST` to insert, but this is just a concept. I suggest you start reading a MVC tutorial, then a Entity Framework tutorial.

Comment: Can you give me some links? I'm just begining with API and I use Db First. Thanks!